# "require() of ES Module [...] is not supported" when using typescript

Tags: typescript, module, fetch, ts-node

My setup is as follows:

I have a `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "discord-app-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec \"yarn start\" --watch src --ext ts,json --ignore *.test.ts",
    "start": "ts-node ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6"
  }
}
```

I have no `tsconfig.json` file as I never need it, normally. Though, somehow when using the `node-fetch` package, I get this error saying "`require() of ES Module [...] is not supported`" even though I am importing it with the ES6 syntax:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

I have tried specifying `"type": "module"` in my package.json, but then I got the error "`Unknown file extension ".ts" for [...]`".

Comment: Did you finally solve it ?

Comment: Where do you get the error? In IDE highlighting? When compiling? When running your `start` script (which uses ts-node)? You haven't shown what verision of ts-node you're using. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `"type": "module"` because this is the new way to
import stuff in node. With this flag you tell node to use ESM for imports which
is the syntax you've used in your question.

ESM is fairly new, so most tools have an opt-in for this and so does `ts-node`,
you've to add the `--esm` argument.

```
$ ts-node --esm ./index.ts
```

Running this still fails with

```bash
$ ts-node --esm ./index.ts
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
    at file:///path/to/index.ts:5:23
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

The error is because of `tsc`s `--module` default which `ts-node` internally
uses.

> [`--target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#target): Default: ES3
>
> [`--module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#module): Default CommonJS if
> target is ES3 or ES5,ES6/ES2015 otherwise.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

`tsc` will transpile scripts to CommonJS, because `--target` default is ES3 and
then the `--module` default is CommonJS.

You can check this by manually running the TypeScript compiler.

index.ts

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";
fetch("https://example.org");
```

```
$ tsc ./index.ts
```

index.js (created by tsc)

```js
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var node_fetch_1 = require("node-fetch");
(0, node_fetch_1["default"])("https://example.org");
```

The .ts file was transpiled for CommonJS (it uses `require`).

When you define `"type": "module"` inside your `package.json`, you tell node to
use the new import syntax, but tsc ignores that and still outputs it in the old
format.

If you want to use the new import syntax natively in node, then you can fix the
problem by defining the module to `nodenext` which describes the ESM support
for node.

```
$ tsc --module nodenext ./index.ts
```

index.js (created by tsc)

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";
fetch("https://example.org");
```

The easiest way to configure the `--module` in for `ts-node` is to create a
`tsconfig.json` with the following content:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext"
  },
  "include": ["*.ts"]
}
```

Now after configuring the module, you can run `ts-node` and it'll hopefully
work well.

```
$ ts-node --esm ./index.ts
```

Here you can read more about ESM support in `ts-node`: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works for me.  You can also use "ts-node-esm" instead of "ts-node --esm".  There does not appear to be a tsconfig option equivalent to the "--esm" flag.  ANyway, the whole feature seems destined to become another of javascript's temporary transitory workarounds that become permanent fixtures.