# How to import map-obj?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to import this lib and I get the following error:

```
/Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/app.controller.js:20
const map_obj_1 = require("map-obj");
                  ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/node_modules/map-obj/index.js from /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/app.controller.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/app.controller.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/app.controller.js:20:19)
```

I wouldn't like to make any significant changes in my package.json that would the project. Though, I tried adding "type": "module" to package.json, it didn't help.

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

The way I do it:

```typescript
import mapObject, { mapObjectSkip } from 'map-obj';
```

I have a basic nestjs `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` files.
Is there any way to import this library in a TS project?

Well it's something that is done in the process of compilation. Weird that it works like this.
Here is what I just tried:

```typescript
let mapObject;
import('map-obj').then((m) => {
  mapObject = m.default;
});
```

and here is what I am getting now:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/node_modules/map-obj/index.js from /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/xml-parser.interceptor.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/xml-parser.interceptor.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/xml-parser.interceptor.js:13:30
```

```
tsconfig.ts
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

```
package.json
```

```json
{
  "name": "xml-controller-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/map-obj": "^3.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^4.3.5",
    "map-obj": "^5.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I'm importing it as `import mapObject, { mapObjectSkip } from 'map-obj';`

And for test using it like this:

```typescript
    mapObject(body, (key: string, value) => [key.toLowerCase(), value], {
      deep: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing an ES module into a CommonJS project. This is not possible using `require()`, however it is possible using `dynamic import`. Note, this is not the same as `static import` suggested by Borodin.

You can do it using callbacks:

```
import('map-obj').then(m => {
  const mapObject = m.default
  const mapObjectSkip = m.mapObjectSkip
})
```

...or using await inside an asynchronous function

```
async function someAsyncFunction() {
  const { default: mapObject, mapObjectSkip } = await import('map-obj')
}
```

Comment: I've just tried it and updated the question, Please, take a look. I think the second option won't work for me, cos it means this lib will be imported on every request, it's definitely something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Do you know any good alternatives to map-obj? Basically, what I'd like to use it for is for serialisation of a json object coming from a third-party API. It looks like this mapper is exactly what I need, it traverses a json recursively and applies a transformation. I didn't want to invent the wheel and just wanted to take advantage of tools available instead, however this lib won't even import which is ridiculous...there should be some alternatives.

Comment: Indeed it seems you had two problems. First, one is stated above. The second one, we'd need more code and information about your compiler setup to be able to answer.

Comment: @Alex By the way, did you notice that you got a new error on the second try? The first one was about `dist/app.controller.js` and the second one is for another file `dist/xml-parser.interceptor.js`. It might simply be that you still have a `require()` in that file. Double check!

Comment: Updated the answer adding more info, please have a look. Checked, it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the proper way should be:

```
import map_obj_1 from "map-obj"
```

Looks like similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69846325/require-of-es-module-is-not-supported-when-using-typescript)

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext"
  },
  "include": ["*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: No, the error is still there. It seems like it just transpiles it into a file where this require is used but it's not supported, looks like a bug to me. https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-obj

Comment: @Alex

Have you tried to add this to tsconfig?

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext"
  },
  "include": ["*.ts"]
}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69846325/require-of-es-module-is-not-supported-when-using-typescript looks like similar issue

Comment: Yep, I'm getting this: `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/alexs/Documents/projects/xml-controller-test/dist/main'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49`